# Stripe - Live Mode / Test Mode with different webooks

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I have a website that uses a WordPress backend and a plugin (Paid Memberships Pro), which connects with Stripe to process payments. This was setup about a year ago, went through full testing to ensure payments were setup, my Stripe account was configured and connected correctly, etc. I have had no problems since then.

However, I'm going to be making some changes to our payment structure, and I would like to test these changes in my testing environment. I have a simple clone of the website that I use for testing, and I would like to link this test site to Stripe as well. However, I'm a bit confused about how I should go about doing this. Do I need to add a new account in Stripe to test this? It appears multiple accounts are meant more for separate businesses, which is not my case. Or, can I add the testing site webhook to Stripe's test mode under the same account (which would be different than the live mode webhook connected to the live site)? Is there another option better suited for this scenario?

Comment: You can either switch your account to test mode, or create a new one for your website copy with test mode enabled (I would go with option 2). Everything can be achieved from the Stripe dashboard in the dev section > webhooks. I do not know Paid Membership Pro as I developed my own plugin tho the basic integration should be the same. Usually you want to understand the basics behind Stripe first, I would suggest looking at the PHP documentation. A few links, the php Stripe GitHub https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php. The php Stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. I'll take a look at this. Just to clarify, it's possible (and ok) to have a webhook in live mode connected to my live site and a wehbook in test mode connected to the test site (i.e. different webhooks under the same account)? I wasn't sure if this would potentially cause issues or wasn't the recommended method for this. I'll look into these docs for more info too.

Comment: No. "Test webhooks" don't exist. Only "test mode or "live mode". Webhooks are just an event being fired when a user do/is updated/is deleted/ ... etc.

Comment: If you switch your website to test mode then pretty much any body will be able to register for free that's why I advise you to test anything on your dev env. More than 250 webhooks exists.

Comment: Thanks for all the info here. I ended up creating a separate account in Stripe (using the same business info for this new test account as my live account), and everything seems to be working correctly. The issue was my understanding of webhooks, as you mentioned. It's best to keep accounts linked to just one website/endpoint between the live/test modes. If you submit your comments (in a shortened form for your convenience) as the answer, I'll accept that!